# Using Perl or Powershell, how to compare 2 CSV files and get only the new rows?

Tags: perl, powershell, csv, compare, diff

I am comparing two large comma-delimited CSV files `File1.csv` and `File2.csv` using the
[`Text::Diff`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Diff) Perl module.
The Perl program is called from a `.bat` file and I put the result in a third file `Diff.csv`

#### Perl

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::Diff;

my $diffs = diff $ARGV[0] => $ARGV[1];

$diffs =~ s/^(?:[^\n]*+\n){2}//;
$diffs =~ s/^(?:[\@ ][^\n]*+)?+\n//mg;

print $diffs;
```

This is how I call the Perl script:

```
perl "C:\diffBetweenTwoFiles.pl" "C:\File1.csv" "C:\File2.csv" > "C:\Diff.csv"
```

One of the columns in the CSV file is `Name`.

Currently the result lists all rows whose values in any columns change, but I want only to list new `Name` rows.

For example:

#### File1.csv

```
"Name","DOB","Address"
"One","1/1/01","5 Stock Rd"
"Two","1/2/02","1 Research Rd"
```

#### File2.csv

```
"Name","DOB","Address"
"One","1/1/01","5 Stock Rd"
"Two","1/2/02","111 Research Rd"
"Three","1/3/03","3 Bold Rd"
```

Currently, the result list these (it includes "Two" because its Address changed):

```
"Name","DOB","Address"
"Two","1/2/02","111 Research Rd"
"Three","1/3/03","3 Bold Rd"
```

But, I only want the result to list the new "Name" like this:

```
"Name","DOB","Address"
"Three","1/3/03","3 Bold Rd"
```

How can I do that in Perl or Powershell script?

Comment: In Powershell you would need to Import the csv using `Import-CSV` . Then you can compare using `Compare-Object`. From there you can `Export-CSV` (or whatever format you wish). If you want to filter out the matches you want you can use `| Where-Object` . That should give you a good starting point. Once you have attempted your own solution, and you are stuck update your OP with your updated script. Then we can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I have tried using Compare-Object before, but because the file is large, it used up all the RAM on my machine and never finished.
Is there any other way to do this, for example using Perl ? The above Perl Script works, except I only want new "Name" rows.

Comment: If you creating the output in Perl, I would assume keeping with Perl would be your best option. Some kind of condition to build your desired output would probably be what you are looking for.  Unfortunately, I am not versed enough on Perl to provide you with the best path to your solution using Perl.

Comment: Here's [a post by Ashley McGlone using hashtables](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ashleymcglone/2017/08/07/use-hash-tables-to-go-faster-than-powershell-compare-object/) that may fit your use case.

Comment: How big exactly are these "large files"? Are they sorted? I think it's clear that it is beyond `Text::Diff` to compare individual fields of a CSV file, and you will need to code something specific.

Comment: Do you really need to output fields other than `Name`, given that the others may have multiple values and you can display only one?

Comment: Do you also want to display values that are in `File1.csv` but not in `File2.csv`, or is `File1.csv` always a subset of the possible values?

Comment: @BenH To use Ashley McGlone's solution, how can I output the "new" rows in file2.txt to another file ? Basically how to put $DifHash into another file ? for ex: Measure-Command -Expression {    Compare-Object2 -ReferenceObject (Get-Content c:\file1.txt) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content c:\file2.txt) -IncludeEqual} | Export-csv "c:\Diff.csv"

Comment: @Borodin Thank you. The 2 files are about 150 Mg each. Text::Diff does work, but it lists all rows when any values in the rows are different between file1 and file2. And, I only want to list those new "Name" rows. I do want to output all other fields other than Name. In my example, in the output file, I want to list the Name, DOB and Address fields for Name "Three". I want to display values that are only in File2, but not in File1.

Comment: @faujong To answer your output question, you would filter with `Where-Object {$_.sideindicator -eq '=>'} | Select -Expand InputObject | out-file C:\diff.csv`. But my comment was merely meant to suggest Hashtables as this doesn't meet your needs as it will compare the full row and requires additional processing. kuujinbo's answer is a full and efficient implementation using a hashtable to compare against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/Text-CSV-1.95/lib/Text/CSV.pm) in Perl

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Text::CSV;

my ($file_old, $file_new, $file_diff) = 
    map { $_ . '.csv' } qw(File1 File2 Diff);

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } )
    or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag();

my ($old, $header) = get_lines($csv, $file_old, 1);
my $new            = get_lines($csv, $file_new);

my @lines_with_new_names = @{ new_names($old, $new) };

open my $fh, '>', $file_diff  or die "Can't open $file_diff: $!";
$csv->say($fh, $header);
$csv->say($fh, $_) for @lines_with_new_names;  # or print with eol set

sub new_names {
    my ($old, $new) = @_;
    my %old = map { $_->[0] => 1 } @$old;
    return [ map { (!exists $old{$_->[0]}) ? $_ : () } @$new ];
}

sub get_lines {
    my ($csv, $file, $return_header) = @_;
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file $!";
    my $header = $csv->getline($fh);  # remove the header line
    return ($return_header) 
        ? ( $csv->getline_all($fh), $header )
        :   $csv->getline_all($fh);
}
```

This prints the correct difference with the provided samples.

Variable names tagged with `old` are related to the file with fewer lines, the other one being `new`.  The "Name" column is taken to be the first one.

Comments

- The `getline_all` method returns an arrayref for all lines, where each is an arrayref with all fields. This is done from a sub, with an option to return the header line as well.
- The optional return of another variable here makes a difference of whether a single scalar or a list is returned, so it can also be handled using [wantarray](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html) builtin

  ```
  return wantarray ? ( LIST ) : scalar;
  ```

  which returns true if the sub is called in a list context.  Thus the caller decides by invoking the sub in either the list or scalar context, `my ($v1, $v2) = f(...)` or `my $v = f(...)`, in which case a flag is not needed in the call. I opted for a more explicit way.
- The difference in names' list is produced in `new_names` sub.  First a lookup hash is made with all names from the "old" arrayref. Then lines in "new" arrayref are filtered, taking those which don't have a name in the "old" (no such key in the hash), and returned in an arrayref `[]`.

  Such use of a hash is a standard technique for finding differences between arrays.

The documented method `say` used for printing doesn't work on my older version of the module with which this is tested.  In that case use `print` and set [eol](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/Text-CSV-1.95/lib/Text/CSV.pm#eol) in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you zdim. It gives me error "Can't locate Class/CSV.pm in @INC.." I found CSV.pm in 3 different location: C:\Perl64\lib\SQL\Dialects\CSV.pm, C:\Perl64\lib\DBD\CSV.pm and C:\Perl64\lib\Bundle\DBD\CSV.pm. I used lib command in the program itself to add the search path like the below, but still get same error : #!/usr/bin/env perl  use lib 'C:\Perl64\lib\Bundle\DBD'; use Class::CSV; use Text::CSV;
Also, in your code, do I replace File1 File2 Diff with c:\File1.txt c:\File2.txt and c:\Diff.csv ? The first 2 files are actually a TXT file, but comma delimited like CSV file.

Comment: @faujong ugh, something is messed up with installation of modules.  (It is worth clearing that up since this is simply a go-to module for CSV.)  As for filenames, you can just list them one per line, what is probably simpler since your third file has a different extension.

Comment: Do you know how I can fix that "Can't locate class/csv.pm in @INC" error ? For the filenames, did you mean to list them like this ? my $file_old = "c:\File1.txt";
my $file_new = "c:\File2.txt";
my $file_diff = "c:\Diff.csv";
(to replace this line my ($file_old, $file_new, $file_diff) = map { $_ . '.csv' } qw(File1 File2 Diff) ) ?

Comment: @faujong  I don't know how Windows installation works, but on my (Linux) system the `CSV.pm` is in a directory `Text/`.  Perhaps you don't have the `Text::CSV` module at all, and your system is picking up some other related ones?  (Also, that `class/csv.pm` is worrisome ... it would refer to a "Class::CSV" module? A typo?)

Comment: OK. I will create a different question on StackOverflow on this error.
As for the filenames, did I understand it correctly ?

Comment: @faujong Yes, update the filenames to what they are.  If the extensions differ it is easier to say `my $file_old = '...'; my $file_new = '...'` -- spell them out.

Comment: @faujong  Updated the answer to also print the header line to output.

Comment: I resolved the "Can't locate text/csv.pm" error by installing TEXT:CSV module from code.activestate.com/ppm/Text-CSV, and tried your code. It works like a charm ! Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working with large files that are stressing your memory limit, you can try:

1. Read the first CSV file one line at a time, and use a hashtable to store the file's Name entries.
2. Read the second CSV file one line at a time and compare it's Name entries against the first.

(**UPDATED** based on comments) A simple example in PowerShell:

```
$output = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder;
$file1 = @{};
$header = $null;

# $filePaths is two-element array with full path to CSV files
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $filePaths.Length; ++$i) {
    $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($filePaths[$i]);
    while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
        if ($line -match '\S') {
            if ($header -eq $null) { 
                $header = $line;
                $output.AppendLine($line) | Out-Null; 
            }
            $name = ($line -split ',')[0];
            switch ($i) {
                0 { $file1.Add($name, $null); }
                1 { 
                    if (!$file1.ContainsKey($name)) { 
                        $output.AppendLine($line) | Out-Null; 
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $reader.Dispose();
}
$output.ToString() | Out-File -FilePath $outPath;
```

Comment: @kuujibo Thank you. I replaced Write-Host $line.Trim() with writing to a file like this: $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\Diff.csv");
while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    $name = ($line -split ',')[0];
    if (!$file1.ContainsKey($name)) { $writer.WriteLine($line.Trim());}
}
But, I am getting the error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." The error is on this line $writer.WriteLine($line.Trim())
Also, how can I also include the header line from File2 to the output file ?

Comment: @faujong - Updated example based on your comments.