# Filter two CSV with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

```
$data1 = Import-Csv "SASSO1.csv" | ?{$_.SourceType -eq "file"} | select "FullPath"
$data2 = Import-Csv "SASSO2.csv" | ?{$_.SourceType -eq "file"} | select "FullPath"

$data1 | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.FullPath -notin $data2 } | Export-Csv "RISULTATO.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

My question is, how to find the difference between the two csv files, where it takes only one column or FullPath?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Perl or Powershell, how to compare 2 CSV files and get only the new rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50590776/using-perl-or-powershell-how-to-compare-2-csv-files-and-get-only-the-new-rows)

Comment: unless I'm misunderstanding something, you should be able to use `Compare-Object` in this case.

Comment: Using this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)): `Import-Csv .\SASSO1.csv |Outer-Join (Import-Csv .\SASSO2.csv) -on FullPath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Compare-Object` to make such comparisons.

**Example**

```
$data1 = @'
FullPath,Name,Desc
a,a,a
b,b,b
c,c,c
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$data2 = @'
FullPath,Name,Desc
d,d,d,
e,e,e
c,c,c
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv


Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $data1 -DifferenceObject $data2 -Property FullPath
```

**Results**

```
FullPath SideIndicator
-------- -------------
d        =>
e        =>
a        <=
b        <=
```

By looking at the results, you can see that the record d and e are in `$data2` only and a and b on `$data1` only.

Based on that, you can export these record or do whatever you want with them.
You can use the `-PassThru` switch if you want to get the complete objects along with the SideIndicator property so you get something like the following results

```
FullPath Name Desc SideIndicator
-------- ---- ---- -------------
d        d    d    =>
e        e    e    =>
a        a    a    <=
b        b    b    <=
```

That way, you can simply select the properties to export `| Select-Object -Property FullPath,Name,Desc` and export all the results that are not in both database.

You can also use the `-IncludeEqual` switch and possibly the `-ExcludeDifferent` switch if instead you want the results present in both csv to be included.

Finally, if you want just one side of the comparison (eg: only the records missing from `$data1`), then you can filter the results using a simple `where` statement (eg: `| Where-Object -Property Sideindicator -eq '=>'`).